# Take away merge button on pull requests without +1?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a team that all has access to the main repository (no need to fork to create PR).

I'd like to make it so that a pull request is not mergeable until a +1 has been giving to the review.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The merge button/ability cannot be taken away from a pull request.

It is possible to use the status API to mark the PR as a 'failed build', making a big red warning on the merge button (http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/), but still no way to prevent a merge.